# LinkageError in JBOSS/Wildfly for HttpClient object in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, http, jboss, wildfly

I have below code and I am trying to run this on JBOSS/WildFly14. But getting below error in eclipse console.

Without 'ResteasyClient' it is working fine( with normal HTTPClient object). But I need ResteasyClient for the proxy setting.

```
try {
            HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return new X509Certificate[0]; }
            }}, new java.security.SecureRandom());

              ApacheHttpClient4Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient4Engine(HttpClient)clientBuilder.build());
              ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                      .httpEngine(engine)             
              .sslContext(sslContext).hostnameVerifier((s1, s2) -> true) .build();           
            return client;          

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            NetqosSharedLogger
                    .error("Unable to configure HttpClient correctly, using fallback connection configuration", ex);
        }
```

> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when
>   resolving method
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.(Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpClient;)V"
>   the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of
>   the current class,
>   com/ca/im/tmi/connector/agent/webservices/ClientUtils, and the class
>   loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for the
>   method's defining class,
>   org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/engines/ApacheHttpClient4Engine, have
>   different Class objects for the type org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
>   used in the signature

Comment: Are you including the Resteasy jars as part of your war file?

Comment: Yes, it is part of my war file.

Comment: Resteasy is included as part of Wildfly.  It looks like the system is getting confused with multiple copies.  One thing to try would be to remove the Resteasy dependencies from your war and use the included ones.

Comment: Problem is Resteasy is part of my maven dependency and maven is creating the war. If I remove that dependency ClassNotFoundExcception is coming for rest easy client.